# Executing a Stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to execute an oracle stored procedure that has an in-out parameter of table of record:

```
TYPE RECORD_TYP IS RECORD (
    CAT_CD                 VARCHAR2(4),
    MOD_ID       NUMBER(6)
);
```

I found this example that talks about `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-passing-array-to-oracle-stored-procedure/.

But what about `List<MyRecordDTO>`?

EDIT: I found an answer here where the poster used an oracle.sql.STRUCT type.
http://betteratoracle.com/posts/32-passing-arrays-of-record-types-between-oracle-and-java

Using this example, I found the exception `java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Inconsistent catalog view`. Googling this exception, I called the DBA to grant me access to "`RECORD_TYP`"

Comment: convert the returned jdbc array construct to a `List<MyRecordDTO>`.  nothing in jdbc will do arbitrary value to POJO conversion for you.

Comment: In fact, the List<MyRecordDTO> is an INOUT parameter and I'm unable to pass this parameter.

Comment: So basically, the last paragraph (about granting access to RECORD_TYP) is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question. But I hope this helps.
Here I am passing a Custom Type Array and in return expecting a Custom type Array.

```
        myJavaRequest req = new myJavaRequest();
        req.setEmpId("940006614");
        myJavaReqArray[0] = req;
        List<myJavaResp> myJavaRespLst = new ArrayList<myJavaResp>();

        try {

            //fetch connection (this should be a OracleConnection class).
            OracleConnection oraConn = (OracleConnection) getConnectionFromDB();

            //Set the mappings -- what is the SQL Object type to Java class mappings when it comes to response.
            Map map = oraConn.getTypeMap();
            map.put("MYSCHEMA.SQLRESPDTO", Class.forName("com.myhome.myJavaResp")); 

            //Create the Array descriptor for the input array
            ArrayDescriptor inputArrayDescr = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("MYSCHEMA.MYREQDTOLIST", oraConn);
            ARRAY inputArray = new ARRAY(inputArrayDescr, oraConn, spgPrefReqArray); //This is an Oracle ARRAY

            //Prepare the Stored procedure call
            OracleCallableStatement stmt  = (OracleCallableStatement)oraConn.prepareCall("{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.PKG.SOME_SP(?) }");
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "MYSCHEMA.SQLRESPDTOLIST");
            stmt.setArray(2, inputArray);

            //Lets execute
            stmt.execute();

            //Fetch the Array of Objects that will have the set of expecting response java objects.
            ARRAY outArray = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getARRAY(1);
            Object[] objects = (Object[])outArray.getArray(map);

            if(null != objects && objects.length > 0){
                for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<objects.length; iIndex++){
                    myJavaRespLst.add((myJavaResp)objects[iIndex]);
                }
            }
        }
```